# How to convert a javascript string to reference an object property?

Tags: javascript, string, object, properties, eval

I have a custom object with a bunch of array properties.

```
function Location (name, displayName){
  this.name = name,
  this.displayName = displayName,
  Location.objects.push(this);                           
}
Location.objects = [];

//Initialize Farm
var farm = new Location();

farm.scenes = [
  "content 0",
  "content 1",
  "Content 2"
];
```

Using JQuery, I am grabbing an attribute from the DOM that I need to use to call values from within the object.

```
$('button').click(function(){
      var location = $(this).attr('id'); //in this case, the id is 'farm'
      mainLoop(location);
});

function mainLoop(location){
  console.log(farm.scenes.length);// returns '3' as desired    
  console.log(location.scenes.length);//returns undefined because location is a string. I need this to work.
  console.log(location[scenes][length]); //same problem
}
```

The only solution I've found this far is to use eval(), but I cannot do that because this data could be manipulated by the end user.

```
function mainLoop(location){
  location = eval(location); 
  console.log(location.scenes.length);//returns 3 as desired
}
```

I need an alternative way to somehow take this string and turn it into an object property reference. In this case, I am working with a limited amount of results, so I could potentially map a set of strings to identifiers, but I feel like there's probably a more elegant solution for this, though I can't figure out what question I should be typing into stackoverflow.

There is a similar question [Dynamically access object property using variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4244896/dynamically-access-object-property-using-variable), but this doesn't apply here - both of the following lines using both forms of notation would have resolved '3'. I think my syntax is correct on the notation, so I must be doing something else incorrectly.

```
console.log(location.scenes.length);    //returns undefined because location is a string. I need this to work.
console.log(location[scenes][length]);  //same problem
```

Answer (score 0):

Since using `location = eval(location);` transforms it into the object you want, I assume that `location` as being passed in to your `mainLoop` function is simply the JSON string representing the object, equivalent to `'{"scenes" : ["content 0", "content 1", "Content 2"]}'`

What you can do is use [`JSON.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) - in this case:

```
console.log(location);
// outputs '{"scenes" : ["content 0", "content 1", "Content 2"]}'
location = JSON.parse(location);
console.log(location.scenes.length); // outputs 3
```

Nowadays, it's pretty much standard in browsers.  There is more information on JSON.parse in [this related SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4935632/parse-json-in-javascript), which points out that if you're already using jquery (which it looks like you are), then you can use `$.parseJSON` which will handle older browsers by falling back to `eval`.